# Performance issue: if (isChecked) vs. if (isChecked == true)

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, runtime, compile-time

Is there any Performance issue in using `if (isChecked)` vs. `if (isChecked == true)` in **Compiletime** or **Runtime**?

Comment: **No**.. Both are same. Syntactically and semantically

Comment: Performance is he same, only `if (isChecked)` has 6 characters less to type on the keyboard

Comment: @Shaharyar: Well no, they're not syntactically the same - they have different syntax trees.

Comment: Of course there is.  Whomever reviews that second version is going to lose an hour of his life trying to figure out why on Earth you'd write it that way.  That's ten trillion cycles he'll never get back.

Comment: @JonSkeet So you mean there is a difference between them at the compile time ?

Comment: @Shaharyar: Well yes, the compiler can tell the difference - you could detect the difference in Roslyn, for example, and suggest a code fix from the long form to the short form.

Comment: What is the type of `isChecked`? It looks like it's probably `bool`, but for other types, there is a significant difference. One I've frequently come across is `bool?`, but there are other types where it makes a difference too.

Comment: @hvd yes it is bool.

Comment: Do you love me? Do you really love me? Do you really really love me? And now, say it in C#: if ( isChecked ) ...; if ( isChecked == true ) ...; if ( isChecked == true == true ) ...; if ( isChecked == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true ) ...; - they all do the same. Just, for me, the shortest versions are easier to understand.

Comment: @HansKlünder Is see but Read the Answer please...

Comment: I know it makes no difference in performance. I just agree with HansPassant and I think that source code should be clear, which means that pointless complications should be avoided. isChecked is already bool. Every additional `==true` distracts from the fact that isChecked is a perfect expression inside the beaces of an if.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No performance issue whatsoever. IL generated for both cases is exactly the same and when IL is the same then execution of it will be the same. So no runtime difference.

```
bool x = true;
if (x == true) // or (x)
    Console.WriteLine("True");

IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  stloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_0008:  ldloc.1     // CS$4$0000
IL_0009:  brtrue.s    IL_0016
IL_000B:  ldstr       "True"
IL_0010:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Install [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and try it yourself next time ;)

As for the compile-time, as mentioned in comments, an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) generated will in fact differ. Here's the relevant part of the AST for `if(x)`

[image]

and now for `if(x == true)`

[image]

You can see the difference.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh I hope it cleared all your questions on the topic.